# Length of an array in a variable

Tags: javascript

My program selects an array based on the last letter of what the user enters and the name of the chosen array is selected. I want to find the length of the arrey that has the same name as the last leter of the word the user inputs. The letter/array selection works but the length doesn't. basicli the style of an word foot ball.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var a = ['quasar','Quebec','quercetin']
var b = ['boron','broky','branka']
var c = ['cop','camera','controler','copito']
//i dint write all of the variables becous it woud be to long but his works as an example.
function hrat() {
  var input = document.getElementById("text").value;

  var lastChar = input.substr(input.length - 1);
  console.log (lastChar);
  console.log ((lastChar).length);
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (lastChar).length);
```

Comment: Since your variable is even called `lastCharacter`, it'll always be a length of 1. Why try to get the length programatically at all?

Comment: Everything here is a string - you don't have any arrays. You can query the length of a string because that property is provided on the String object. But, the length of `lastChar` is 1 - it is a single character - not a String object - it has no length property. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you can just use `lastChar.length`, no need to put `lastChar` in parens.

Comment: Why would a single character have a length other than 1? Did you mean to reference input length? What did you think `lastChar.length` is actually returning?

Comment: What do you want ? Any words last character is always be 1.

Comment: question is not clear at all. try to provide more detail.

Comment: @Webber i updated the code show more how i mean it. iam triing to get the lenght of the variable which is named as the last leter of the word the user tipes in. to chose a random string from that array. basicli a word football if you are familiar

Comment: @Randy Casburn it think i already anserd all of what you ask in my coment to Webber thanks for helping

Comment: @TaimoorQureshi i updated the question hope that hepls also made a coment that expleines some parts to more detaile in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want something like this.

```js
const DATA = {
    search: {
    a: ['quasar','Quebec','quercetin'],
        b: ['boron','broky','branka'],
        c: ['cop','camera','controler','copito'],
  }
}

const getSearchEntryArray = (value) => {
    const {search} = DATA;
  const output = search[value];
  return output || [];
}

const getRandomIndex = (array) => {
    return array.length > 0 ? Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length) : -1 ;
}

const getOutput = (value) => {
    const resultArray = getSearchEntryArray(value);
  const index = getRandomIndex(resultArray);
  
  return resultArray[index];
}

const hrat = () => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
  const input_text = document.getElementById("text");
  
  const input = {
    _value: input_text.value,
    get lastChar() {
        return this._value.substr(this._value.length - 1);
    },
  };
  
  console.log(getOutput(input.lastChar));

  input_text.value = '';
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="hrat()">
  <input id="text">
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I just understand is you are taking the input of an array identifier and then check the length of that array. please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
var a = ['quasar','Quebec','quercetin']
var b = ['boron','broky','branka']
var c = ['cop','camera','controler','copito']
//i dint write all of the variables becous it woud be to long but his works as an example.
function hrat() {
  var input = document.getElementById("text").value;

  var lastChar = input.substr(input.length - 1);
  console.log (lastChar);

  console.log (this[lastChar].length);
  //OR
  console.log (window[lastChar].length)

var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * this[lastChar].length);
```